# Populate Image Object from URL

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to populate an Image Object from a URL located in a workbook cell. I did read that a Label Object could also be populated with picture but nothing about using a URL. In Cell N1 I have a link to a picture on the internet. I would like the Image Object to use the link located in N1. Currently I have a button that opens the URL in a browser, but the client (My Wife) would rather have it open in an Image Object or a Label Object. Below is what I currently have.

```
Private Sub btnPicture_Click()

If Me.cmbInvID <> "" Then
    Me.btnPicture.Visible = True
End If

 'loop thru ws to find current item

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory")

wsLR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To wsLR
    If ws.Cells(x, 1) = Me.cmbInvID And Me.tbURL <> "" Then
        currentrow = x
        'get item
        Me.tbURL = ws.Cells(x, "N")
            ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Me.tbURL
        Exit Sub

        ElseIf ws.Cells(x, 1) = Me.cmbInvID And Me.tbURL = "" Then
        currentrow = x
        'Set message box
        MsgBox "No Picture Available"

        Exit Sub
   End If

Next x

'This is the actual link that I am following for this example
'ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "https://www.facebook.com/VariousStyleShop/photos/a.513162572116670.1073741865.314715208628075/606029979496595/?type=3&theater"

End Sub
```

Comment: What I have here already works, but it pulls up a the picture in a web browser.  What I was hoping for was to link it to an Image Object.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is not an image but a link to a script on Facebook's site. Keep rooting in Facebook until you get the actual image `*.jpg`, `*.png`, etc.

I'll bet that if you pull some random image from Google/imagur/500pix/etc that ends with `.jpg` what you've got will work just fine.